# sortedResultsUsingProperty realm iOS

Tags: ios, sorting, realm

in iOS realm has the ability to return a sorted RLMResults from your database.

```
sortedResultsUsingProperty(..)
```

Is it possible to 'not return anything, and just to actually sort your locally saved database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm does not currently have any way to sort all of your objects in place, as it doesn't make any guarantees about the order objects are stored in the underlying database (which allows for better performance). Most of the time, however, sorting an `RLMResults` is going to be fast enough that it's not a concern.